# Update fields based on other fields in the table

Tags: sql, oracle

**table**

```
id | term | parent | prev_id | title
---+------+--------+---------+-------
 1 | 2015 |      2 |       0 | red child
 2 | 2015 |      0 |       0 | 2015 parent
 3 | 2015 |      2 |       0 | green child
 4 | 2015 |      2 |       0 | blue child
-----------------------------+------------
 5 | 2016 |      0 |       1 | red child
 6 | 2016 |      0 |       2 | 2016 parent
 7 | 2016 |      0 |       3 | green child
 8 | 2016 |      0 |       4 | blue child
```

Every year moving forward, the data is copied over. The `prev_id` field is updated to the previous id for the previous term, but the `parent` field is cleared and needs to be updated with the new parent ids. I have a feeling I need a subquery, but I'm stuck on where to go from here. This is probably easy and I'm overthinking things...

```
select a1.id prev_id,
       a1.term prev_term,
       a1.parent prev_parent,
       a2.id new_id,
       a2.term new_term,
       a2.parent new_parent
  from table a1,
       table a2
 where a1.id = a2.prev_id
```

Expected output:

```
id | term | parent | prev_id | title
---+------+--------+---------+-------
 1 | 2015 |      2 |       0 | red child
 2 | 2015 |      0 |       0 | 2015 parent
 3 | 2015 |      2 |       0 | green child
 4 | 2015 |      2 |       0 | blue child
-----------------------------+------------
 5 | 2016 |      6 |       1 | red child
 6 | 2016 |      0 |       2 | 2016 parent
 7 | 2016 |      6 |       3 | green child
 8 | 2016 |      6 |       4 | blue child
```

Comment: RDBMS I'm using is Oracle

Comment: You need the query to copy data every year? One more thing that is this parent - child only or 2 level or more ( I means could it have 1 more row id= 11 with parent = 1 ?)

Comment: This kind of problem can sometimes be attributed to poor design

Comment: Are you looking for an update statement, or for an insert (adding the four rows for 2016, where the initial table had only the rows up to and including 2015)? It's not very clear from your description. For example, you said the prev_id is updated to the previous id, but in your tables the prev_id column is exactly the same "before" and "after". Also, the parent column is changed (only for the 2016 rows); that part can be done with an UPDATE statement.

Comment: The insert statement already exists in a really outdated process. I am looking for an update statement to just update the parent fields.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get rid of the practice of listing your tables in the `WHERE` clause. It's a syntax that has been obsolete for 20+ years and is error prone. Explicitly `JOIN` your tables together. Always.

I'm sure that there is an issue with the design itself judging by the pattern that you're using, but without knowing the requirements of the system I can't say much beyond that.

As to your query, the following should do what you need:

```
UPDATE NEW_CHILD
SET
    parent = NEW_PARENT.id
FROM
    My_Table NEW_PARENT
INNER JOIN My_Table OLD_PARENT ON
    OLD_PARENT.id = NEW_PARENT.prev_id AND
    OLD_PARENT.parent = 0
INNER JOIN My_Table OLD_CHILD ON
    OLD_CHILD.parent = OLD_PARENT.id
INNER JOIN My_Table NEW_CHILD ON
    NEW_CHILD.parent = NEW_PARENT.id AND
    NEW_CHILD.prev_id = OLD_CHILD.id
WHERE
    NEW_PARENT.parent = 0 AND
    NEW_PARENT.term = '2016'
```